# Laravel migration and PostgreSQL schemas

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I'm using **PostgreSQL** and want to try Laravel.

First - my `up()` function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('entries.entries', function($t) {

        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('username', 50);
        $t->string('email', 100);
        $t->text('comment');
        $t->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And i have two questions:

**1)** I haven't shema `entries` in my database, so, how can i change my up function to create it too? I dont want to do it manually.

**2)** I got an error when executed migration:

```
 sudo php artisan migrate

 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
     SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  no schema has been selected  
     to create in (SQL: create table "emigrations" ("migration" varchar(255) not null,
     "batch" integer not null))
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Well i know that this question has more than 2 year's... but for the future people that reaches this. Laravel does not recognize the default 'public' schema of postgres by default and that's why you get the:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
     SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  no schema has been selected
     to create in (SQL: create table "emigrations" ("migration" varchar(255) not null,
     "batch" integer not null))

Thus to solve this error you just rename your Schema in postgres to anything besides public and, in your laravel project in the file config/database.php change the name of your pgsql conection schema to the one you want to use in your DB.

This should solve it.

It did for me anyways...

Answer (score 2):

1) I don't think there is such functionality in Laravel but you can use an external package like https://github.com/pacuna/Laravel-PGSchema

2) Did you remove the default schema in your app/config/database.php file?

```
'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'forge',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel and PostgreSQL DB Connection, Authentication, Migration:

**Prerequisites***

- PHP 7.2+
- Composer (a dependency manager for PHP)
- PostgreSQL 9.5+

**Installing Laravel**

Create a new project with auth scaffolding.

`laravel new blog --auth`

Now Change default db connection in blog\config\database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
change to
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

- Next, we’ll need to configure our database credentials in Laravel by updating the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=projectmanager
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

Finally, we have to enable the PostgreSQL driver in our php.ini file. Let’s go into our XAMPP/WAMP directory and modify this file by commenting out these two drivers:

```
- extension=pdo_pgsql
- extension=pgsql
```

Note: check php.ini file location is bin\php\php7.3.5. Also, check the php.ini file is PHP or apache file.

Then Run migration for creating the table.

`php artisan migrate`

Now you get your final output.

Thanks and best of luck.